# To return number of swaps in the bubble sort

Tags: bubble-sort

Why this getNumSwaps() method do not return the value of instance  variable **numberOfSwaps**

**In the main function the method is called but its fruitless**

```
public class Solution {
 public int numberOfSwaps;
Solution(){} 
   public int[] bubbleSort(int[] x){  // To sort the array
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {  
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length - 1; j++) {
            if (x[j] > x[j + 1]) {
               int tmp = x[j];
                x[j] = x[j + 1];
                x[j + 1] = tmp;
              this.numberOfSwaps++;//This counts the number of Swaps  
             }
         }
         if (numberOfSwaps == 0) {
        break;
         }
   }
    return x;
}
public int getNumOfSwaps(){ //this method returns zero. ??
    return this.numberOfSwaps;
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         int arrLength=sc.nextInt();int i=0;
          int [] myArry=new int[arrLength];
          Solution sln=new Solution();   
          while(i<arrLength){
            myArry[i]=sc.nextInt();
             i++; 
        }
      System.out.println("Array is sorted in "+sln.getNumOfSwaps()+" swaps.");
      System.out.println("First Element: "+sln.bubbleSort(myArry)[0]+
                         "\nLast Element: "+sln.bubbleSort(myArry)[arrLength-1]);  
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `getNumOfSwaps()` *before* you actually sort the array, hence you are getting the default value of zero.  Your `main()` method should look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arrLength = sc.nextInt();
    int i = 0;
    int[] myArry = new int[arrLength];
    Solution sln = new Solution();   
    while (i < arrLength) {
        myArry[i] = sc.nextInt();
        i++; 
    }

    // first sort the array, populating the number of swaps counter
    int[] myArrySorted = sln.bubbleSort(myArry);

    // then access the number of swaps counter
    System.out.println("Array is sorted in " + sln.getNumOfSwaps() + " swaps.");
    System.out.println("First Element: " + myArrySorted[0] +
                       "\nLast Element: "  + myArrySorted[arrLength-1]);
}
```

I am also assuming that your implementation of bubble sort be correct.  In any case, my answer should explain the reason you were getting zero instead of some value.

Comment: @Op and to answer the next question: you need to reset the counter at the beginning of the sort function if you plan to call it more than once.

Comment: @ABuckau I don't think the number of swaps should be a persistent variable in the first place, and besides this the algorithm could be off, I never checked it myself.

Comment: Should vs What Op actually posted * edit: also since arrays are passed by reference, the return value is a little weird..pointless, but does provide syntactic sugar I guess - no point in confusing a newbie.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Yes got the result.